# Angular Unit tests failing with undefined / no provider

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I could really require some help I have about 12 component that I am failing to test because of the same issues. I've been sitting on this for about 15 hours and really haven't made much progress I think maybe my mocks are wrong. I'll just pick a random one as an example of the problems.

I am using Karma and Jasmine to test within an Angular 10 development environment

The component is called ArchivedUserStoryOverview and I've made an own controller to interact with Firebase, I am mocking out the observables this would return completely (or at least that's what I think I am doing). It's important to note that my app runs without bugs issues that occur when I test.

Actual Component: Archiveduserstoryoverview.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseController } from '../../services/firebase-controller';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-archiveduserstoryoverview',
  templateUrl: './archiveduserstoryoverview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./archiveduserstoryoverview.component.css']
})
export class ArchiveduserstoryoverviewComponent implements OnInit {
  projectId: string;
  userstoryArray: Array<any>;
  assigneeArray: Array<string>;

  constructor(public firebaseController: FirebaseController, private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.userstoryArray = new Array<any>();
    this.assigneeArray = new Array<string>();
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.setProjectId(params["id"]));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.firebaseController.getUserstoriesSnapshot().subscribe(res => {
      res.forEach(item => {
        if(item.payload.val()['ProjectId'] == this.projectId){
          this.userstoryArray.push([item.key, item.payload.val()]);
          this.getUserNameByKey(item.payload.val()['AssignedUser']);
        }
      })
    });
  }

  setProjectId(id){
    this.projectId = id;
  }

  // Returns the username for a given user key
  private getUserNameByKey(userKey: string): any {
    this.firebaseController.getUserByKey(userKey).subscribe(a => {
      const data = a.payload.val();
      const id = a.key;
      this.assigneeArray.push(data['Name']);
    });
  }

  deArchiveUserstory(key){
    this.firebaseController.deArchiveUserstory(key);
  }
}
```

Test component: Archiveduserstoryoverview.component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ArchiveduserstoryoverviewComponent } from './archiveduserstoryoverview.component';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';
import {FirebaseController} from '../../services/firebase-controller';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {AppModule} from '../../app.module';

describe('ArchiveduserstoryoverviewComponent', () => {
  let component: ArchiveduserstoryoverviewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ArchiveduserstoryoverviewComponent>;

  let fixtureUserstories = [
    {
      "-MFR0QIUc7tA3tAES5Zb" : {
        "AssignedUser" : "-MEZSC3KJvUynPd98kcH",
        "Description" : "",
        "EndDate" : "2020-02-22",
        "ProjectId" : "0",
        "SprintId" : "0",
        "Status" : "New",
        "Storypoints" : "",
        "Title" : "Frondend1"
      },
      "-MFRd7PsweHm07JUhZjA" : {
        "AssignedUser" : "",
        "Description" : "div links uitlijnen",
        "EndDate" : "2020-02-24",
        "ProjectId" : "0",
        "SprintId" : "-MFCHMDwfK84cVUdXosO",
        "Status" : "Archived",
        "Storypoints" : 1,
        "Title" : "About us fiksen"
      },
      "-MFRdG-biiv_okiRSWvi" : {
        "AssignedUser" : "-MEZSCn1yv9Yjo3eK4pr",
        "Description" : "nieuwe versie van angular",
        "EndDate" : "2020-02-25",
        "ProjectId" : "0",
        "SprintId" : "-MFCHMDwfK84cVUdXosO",
        "Status" : "New",
        "Storypoints" : 20,
        "Title" : "Updaten"
      }
    }
  ];
  let mockUserstories$ = of(fixtureUserstories);

  let fixtureUsers = [
    {
      "-MEZSC3KJvUynPd98kcH" : {
        "Name" : "Mitch"
      },
      "-MEZSCn1yv9Yjo3eK4pr" : {
        "Name" : "Maarten"
      },
      "-MEgdGlEPzDi1h32gTbH" : {
        "Name" : "John Doe"
      },
      "-MFYR3ln26SB8JjdE8eS" : {
        "Name" : "test"
      }
    }
    ]

  let mockUsers$ = of(fixtureUsers);

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    const fakeAFDB = jasmine.createSpyObj('FireBaseController', [ 'getUserstoriesSnapshot', 'getUserNameByKey']);

    fakeAFDB.getUserstoriesSnapshot.and.callFake(function() {
      return mockUserstories$;
    });

    fakeAFDB.getUserNameByKey('-MFYR3ln26SB8JjdE8eS').and.callFake(function() {
      return mockUsers$;
    });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule, AppModule
      ],
      declarations: [ ArchiveduserstoryoverviewComponent ],
      providers: [ { provide: FirebaseController, useValue: fakeAFDB  }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ArchiveduserstoryoverviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I start by creating Userstories and Users, the structure is just a snippet from the Firebase back-end.

Now when I run all my tests it gives these three errors:

I'm not sure what the "And" means in this instance, I used to think it was missing on the of the Methods that had to be called that I didn't stub or mock, but this seems to be false

Failed: Cannot read property 'and' of undefined

```
at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/views/archiveduserstoryoverview/archiveduserstoryoverview.component.spec.ts:75:54)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:1032:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:289:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:363:1)
    at Zone.runGuarded (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:133:1)
    at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:1154:1)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:1092:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
```

Really strange one, AngularFireDatabase isn't even made because I am completely mocking out my own controller

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[FirebaseController -> AngularFireDatabase -> AngularFireDatabase]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireDatabase!

```
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'FirebaseController', 'AngularFireDatabase', 'AngularFireDatabase' ] })
    at <Jasmine>
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:915:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11081:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11081:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:801:1)
    at ɵɵinject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:805:1)
    at Object.FirebaseController_Factory [as factory] (ng:///FirebaseController/ɵfac.js:5:46)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11248:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11070:1)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:24198:1)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:22101:1)
```

This one makes sense, the test doesn't pass

Expected undefined to be truthy.

```
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/views/archiveduserstoryoverview/archiveduserstoryoverview.component.spec.ts:96:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:292:1)
```

I am so incredibly stuck on this I have rewritten the way I mock multiple times and I really cannot seem to solve it, if anyone please has the time to give me a hand? Let me know if you'd like to see any other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest issue is that you're importing `AppModule`. Your app module is going to bring in all of your module's dependencies - you should only import what this particular component needs, which is exclusively the `RouterTestingModule`.

Once you remove that you should no longer get an error about `AngularFireDatabase`. What was likely to be happening is that since AppModule was providing the real FirebaseController service it was using the one from AppModule first.

Next issue - in your component you have a method named `getUserNameByKey` and it calls `this.firebaseController.getUserByKey`. Your `fakeAFDB` should have `getUserByKey`.

Third issue -

```
fakeAFDB.getUserNameByKey('-MFYR3ln26SB8JjdE8eS').and.callFake(function() {
      return mockUsers$;
    });
```

Notice how you're calling the function here? With any fake you are defining the function, not invoking it. The way to do this is `fakeAFDB.getUserByKey.and.callFake(function () { return mockUsers$; });`

Now, written this way you will be returning the exact same value no matter what is passed in. If you want to do logic on that you can do something like

```
fakeAFDB.getUserByKey.and.callFake(function (key) {
  if (key = 'some string'){
    return mockUsers$;
  }
  return someOtherResult;
});
```

Here is the final solution you're looking for. This will still throw errors, however, after you call `fixture.detectChanges` as the code in your controller's ngOnInit looks at `if(item.payload.val()['ProjectId'] == this.projectId){` and your `getUserstoriesSnapshot` result doesn't have a `val` function defined. I trust that you can modify your fake results accordingly.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    const fakeAFDB = jasmine.createSpyObj<FirebaseController>('FireBaseController', ['getUserstoriesSnapshot', 'getUserByKey']);
    // returnValue is better here since you don't need logic on the return
    fakeAFDB.getUserstoriesSnapshot.and.returnValue(mockUserstories$);

    fakeAFDB.getUserByKey.and.callFake(() => {
      return mockUsers$;
    });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ArchiveduserstoryoverviewComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [ { provide: FirebaseController, useValue: fakeAFDB  }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fixes some of the issues I had, a majority of the other issues were solved by moving the non async code to the end of the async code